# DB2 Client Installation Error

Tags: database, db2, database-installation

I am facing problems while installaing **db2** client in my system. Initially I got an error: `Cannot find XML_0017.cab`.

Then I cancelled the installation, selected the custom installation option and removed all the options related to XML (i.e. XML Extender and the XML Extender Samples) and tried to install. Now i can see that `WEBD0000.CAB` file is missing.

I am not able to understand how to proceed with the installation. Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of the client are you installing?  Where did you download it?  Have you tried re-downloading the client from IBM?

Comment: The version is 9.1, got it from my friend. Can you refer the link for download which wont cause any problem at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 9.1 was not supported on Windows 7 at all.  IBM ended support of DB2 9.1 in April, 2012.

I would suggest you download a more recent version of the Data Server client from [IBM's website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg27007053).

Answer (score 0):

CAB file, I assume this is a windows installation.
My DB2 on windows is a little rusty but if this is a client install you should not have to install "XML anything" unless you installing some kind of addon for Visual Studio.
What file did you download?
Can you include a file name, url link etc.?

Comment: Yes, ita a windows installation (Windows 7 Home Basic). I got the setup from my friend. Can you refer the link for download which wont cause any problem at all?